# beginner question: openMP for a loop that uses its own data

Tags: loops, openmp

Sorry if the title is not decsribing this accurately! I am new to OMP and trying to make this loop parallel. I am struggling with critical, atomic and locks but can't get it to work. b is an array of doubles with size n.

The result is not the same as when I remove the omp code

My real code is more ocmplex but if I can understand the use of OMP on this it would be a great help

```
#pragma omp parallel
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
 {
    double v = 0;
     
    #pragma omp critical
    for (int j=i-1; j <= i+1; j++)
       if (j >= 0 && j < n)
           v += b[j];
   
    b[i] = somecalculation(v);
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct algorithm you wish to use? You may intend to use the following: `bnew[i]=somecalculation(v);` after the loop copy `bnew` array back to `b`. If so, it can easily be parallelized.

Comment: @Laci That doesn't work because `b[i]` is a function of `b[i-1]`. There is a strict recurrence.

Comment: Your code as given is not quite complete. Given that `b[0]` is a function of `b[1]`, how is `b` initialized? With zero? Are you maybe doing an SOR method on a tridiagonal matrix? In that case there is an outer loop, and you can make this parallel by rewriting the loop nest. However, that is not quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. You use `#pragma omp parallel` but it looks like you want `#pragma omp parallel for`. The way you have written it, every thread executed every iteration of the loop, practically calculating everything multiple times
2. Your critical section ends after the loop. It does not cover the update of `b[i]`. However, the calculation of `i+1` depends on the result of `i`

How to fix this: I don't think you can. The code doesn't seem parallelizable in any meaningful way because every iteration depends on the result of the last one.